# Distribution of a r.v. with the same mean and variance is abs. cont. with resp. to the normal distr.

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, random-variables

I have a question concerning the Kullback-Leibler divergence or relative entropy.

In a book I found the following definition of the KL-divergence:
Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F)$ be a measurable space. Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be $\sigma$-finite measures on $(\Omega, \mathcal F)$ and suppose that $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\nu$. Then the KL-divergence from $\mu$ to $\nu$ is defined as
\begin{align*}
D_{KL}(\mu ||\nu) := \int_\Omega \log \frac{d\mu}{d\nu} \, d\mu,
\end{align*}
where $\frac{d\mu}{d\nu}$ is the Radon-Nikodym derivative. If $\mu$ is not absolutely continous with respect to $\nu$ we set $D_{KL}(\mu || \nu) = +\infty$.

Now let us consider the case where we have a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$. In a paper which I am studying currently, I have the claim which I do not understand:

Let $X, Y$ be random variables where $X$ has a density $f$ and $Y$ is normally distributed with the same mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ as $X$. Then
\begin{align*}
D_{KL}(\mathbb P^X || \mathcal N(\mu, \sigma^2)) = \int_{\mathbb R} f(x) \log \frac{f(x)}{\phi_Y(x)} \, dx,
\end{align*}
where $\phi_Y$ denotes the normal density.

What I do not understand is, why is $\mathbb P^X$ absolutely continuous with respect to the normal distribution?

Thanks.

Comment: Because $X$ has a density hence $P^X\ll\mathrm{Lebesgue}\ll\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ for every nonzero $\sigma^2$.

Comment: Ah, so I actually need to proof that the Lebesgue measure is absolutely continuous with respect to the normal distribution. Is that a long task? And why does one need the assumption that $Y$ has the same mean and variance?

Comment: "Is that a long task?" Are you serious? Just write down the definition of these two measures and the definition of absolute continuity. "And why does one need the assumption that Y has the same mean and variance?" For this specific step, one does not need it, actually every nondegenerate normal density is absolutely continuous with respect to every other nondegenerate normal density.

Comment: Just out of interest @numerion, what paper is it that you are studying? I'm looking for work on a question related to this...